# azure createBlockBlobFromLocalFile shows no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I am trying to uploading file using `azure-storage` function `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile()`. But when i upload the file i am getting error like

> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\path\task1.txt'
>   errno: -4058,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'stat',   path:
>   'D:\path\task1.txt' }

But my file is inside the same path that i am using to run the file. So this means the uploading file and code both in same folder. Here is the code which i am trying to upload

```
var azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
var blobUri = "http://accountname.blob.core.windows.net";
var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey).withFilter(new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());
blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('container', 'taskblob', 'task1.txt', function(error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("uplaoded");
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I reused your sample code above with slight modifications on the blobUri and added the sasKey value and I am able to upload a new block blob to my storage account blob container.

[image]

**Please make sure that your JavaScript code file above is in the same path as your text file to be uploaded**, i.e.

```
D:\path\yoursamplejs.js
D:\path\task1.txt
```

To run your script, do this:

```
D:\path\node yoursamplejs.js
```

You should expect to see the result output as: **"uplaoded"** in your case.

I have tested this working with:

**azure-storage** node module version: **2.8.0**

**Node.js** version: **8.9.4**

**npm** version: **5.6.0**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am following the same folder structure. But still i am getting the error as `events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, read`

Comment: Also what are the versions of the above you are using?

Comment: i am using node.js 8.9.1, npm 5.5.1 & azure-storage 2.8.0

Comment: How and where do you execute your script?

Comment: I am running the script my local system. js file is available in `D:\path\upload.js` and uploading file is available in same path `D:\path\task1.txt`. I am running the code inside the path folder like `D:\path\node upload.js`

Comment: What OS and version are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166078/discussion-between-juvchan-and-satheesh).