# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, read

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-node-sdk

I am using `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile()` function to upload the file to `azure-storage`. Here is the code,

```
var azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
var blobUri = "http://accountname.blob.core.windows.net";
var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey).withFilter(new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());
blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('container', 'taskblob', 'task1.txt', function(error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("uploaded");
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
```

when i run the above code i am getting error like

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, read

My file path and code are in same folder like

```
D:\path\upload.js

D:\path\task1.txt
```

I checked the file availability using below code, it returns as success,

```
var fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync('task1.txt')) { }
```

Please someone suggest me a solution for this,

UPDATE : Error message is different from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050378/azure-createblockblobfromlocalfile-shows-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Have you tried passing the absolute path?

Comment: yes i tried absolute path also like  `blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('container', 'taskblob', 'D:\path\task1.txt', function(error, result, response) { }` but not working. still the same error

Comment: i also tried `var path = require('path'); path.join(__dirname, 'task1.txt')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [azure createBlockBlobFromLocalFile shows no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050378/azure-createblockblobfromlocalfile-shows-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have read permission to that file? You can test it such as by creating a file read stream to read the file content.

I tested following code with azure-storage-node@2.8.0, and it works well.

```
var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(accountName, sasKey).withFilter(new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());

blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('mycontainer', function (err, res) {
  if (!err) {
    blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer', 'taskblob', 'task1.txt', function (error, result, response) {
      if (!error) {
          console.log("uploaded");
      } else {
          console.log(error);
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```